# Adding a short sleep to mysql query to debug caching

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I'd like to make a sql query sleep for a couple of seconds to verify if my application caches the query result properly.

I tried to add `SLEEP(2)` to the select query, which results in mysql hanging up until it gets restarted.

Also tried to add a `DO SLEEP(2);` line before the actual query, which made php throw a "General Error" Exception.

Here's some example code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... HUGE LIST OF THINGS";
$result = $myCachedDatabase->query($sql); // Does this actually cache the query result? Or does it perform the query every time?
```

What I'd like is something along of this:

```
$sql = "DELAY(5 seconds); SELECT ... HUGE LIST OF THINGS";
$result = $myCachedDatabase->query($sql); // First time it took 5s, second time it was instant - yay it gets cached!
```

the `DELAY(5 seconds);` is the part I'm looking for

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is unclear from your question where and how you implement your attempts. Please add real code examples so that we can get a better impression.

Comment: Double-check your PHP database library and verify that: 1) It accepts multiple statements in a single query. 2) It's configured to display errors (or you do the check yourself).